# converting c style string to c++ style string

Tags: c++, c-strings

Can anyone please tell me how to convert a C style string (i.e a char* ) to a c++ style string (i.e. std::string) in a C++ program?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::string` can take a `char *` as a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) parameter, and via a number of operators.

```
char * mystr = "asdf";
std::string mycppstr(mystr);
```

or for the language lawyers

```
const char * mystr = "asdf";
std::string mycppstr(mystr);
```

Comment: I wonder why does everybody responding to this use the flawed (but permitted by the standard) char* type for string literals. All string literals are read-only and thus char const* type should be used. The argument taken by std::string is also char const*.

Comment: so if I have C type string in a char* variable, then how do I convert it to a C++ style string given that strictly speaking the parameter to the constructor should be char const* type?

Comment: @assassin: you don't have char* at all, but your C type string is a char const*. If it is your code, you can change it, if it is in a library, you cannot.

Comment: by char* I meant that my C type string is a null terminated character array, pointed to by a char* pointer(say like the char *mystr="asds"; in the example by John above). So given this is std::string mycppstr(mystr); statement gonna give me a valid conversion?

Comment: Yes, it will be valid. Tronic's point is absolutely valid, but not really practically important for the sake of this example.

Answer (score 10):

```
char* cstr = //... some allocated C string

std::string str(cstr);
```

The contents of `cstr` will be copied to `str`.

This can be used in operations too like:

```
std::string concat = somestr + std::string(cstr);
```

Where `somestr` is already `std::string``

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `string` [class constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) which takes a `char*` as argument.

```
char *str = "some c style string";
string obj(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the conversion is to call a function which takes a `const std::string&` as a parameter:

```
void foo(const std::string& str);

void bar()
{
    char* str= ...

    foo(str);
}
```

I think its a lot more tidy to do the conversion at a function call boundary.

Comment: are you saying that foo should be an empty function here and upon calling that function str gets converted to const std::string type?

Comment: @assassin: No, sorry. `foo()` is any function that takes a `const std::string&`.  It could be one you write.  My answer was just a pattern of usage where you have a c-string and want to convert it.  It also separates the parts of the code where a c-string is generated from where the data is used in the form of a `std::string`.